# Comparing in SQL and SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I really couldn't figure out a good title for this question, but I have a problem that I'm sure you can help me with!

I have a query which outputs something like this:

```
Month | Year | Subcategory | PrivateLabel | Price
-------------------------------------------------
  1   | 2010 | 666         | No           | -520
  1   | 2010 | 666         | No           | -499,75
  1   | 2010 | 666         | No           | -59,95
  1   | 2010 | 666         | No           | -49,73
  1   | 2010 | 666         | No           | -32,95
```

I want to `SUM` on the price because all the other data is the same. I thought I could do this with `SUM` and `GROUP BY`, but I can't figure out how to do it or at least it doesn't output the right result.

The query is an inner join between two tables, if that helps.

Comment: Argh it looks a mess.. It should resemble a table!

Comment: I edited it to format better.. the edit has to be approved but all I did was 4 spaces to the start of each line

Comment: Please post your query and desired output. This helps immensely.

Comment: Your table is nice, it can be pasted directly in http://sqlfiddle.com Text to DDL, and it would automatically create a CREATE TABLE statement. But it would be better, if you also put  sample data formatted same as above. And then put also your desired output

Comment: Okay, so I've tried your solutions and it seems to be working (sort of). It still calculates wrong, bot now it just seems that the last value is counted twice? Does that make sense?

Comment: @MichaelBuen Thank you very much for sqlfiddle! I've been searching for this kind of web-site for a long time.

Comment: No, wait, it doesn't work as i thought :(

Comment: Try to this same question style, with sample data, and with the expected output. Guesswork could be avoided. Pictures(I regarded those sample data and expected output as pictures [ツ](http://xkcd.com/541/) ) are worth a thousand words http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460992/sql-select-sum-of-each-individual-value-of-a-column

Comment: Okay, so I got it to work now.. There was an error in my INNER JOIN. Now, however, I'm able to calculate the TotalPrice, but I'm missing a lot of data from the original INNER JOIN, which I cannot SELECT cause then i have to GROUP it aswell, which will not work. How do you come around this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select
   month
   ,year
   ,subcategory
   ,privatelabel
   ,sum(price) as [total sales]
from
   a inner join b ...
where
   any where clauses 
group by
   month
   ,year
   ,subcategory
   ,privatelabel
```

should work if i am understanding you correctly.. every colum in the select either needs to be part of the group by or an aggregate function on all rows in the group

added a fiddle.. mainly as i didn't know about he text to DDL functionality and wanted to test it ;-) (thanks Michael Buen)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35c1c/1

note the where clause is a place holder..

Answer (score 0):

```
select month, year, subcategory, privatelabel, sum(price)
  from (put your query in here) dummyName
 group by month, year, subcategory, privatelabel
```

Basic idea is it will run your current query to get above output then do the sum and group by on the result. 
You query has to be in parentheses and you have to give it some name e.g. dummyName. As long as it's unique in the sql and preferably not a key word, doesn't matter what it is.

There might be a way of doing all this in one go, but without the sql for your query we can't help.