# SQL: Select sum of each individual value of a column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

There is a column that can have several values. I want to select a count of how many times each distinct value occurs in the entire set. I feel like there's probably an obvious solution but it's eluding me. I'll show input & expected output, hopefully it's obvious enough that you'll understand.

This is example data:

```
|-------|
| class |
|-------|
| 5     |
| 5     |
| 12    |
| 4     |
| 12    |
|-------|
```

This is the output I'm trying to get:

```
|-------|-------|
| class | count |
|-------|-------|
| 5     | 2     |
| 12    | 2     |
| 4     | 1     |
|-------|-------|
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT CLASS, COUNT (*)
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY CLASS
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select class, count(1)
from table
group by class
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
SELECT class , count( class ) AS COUNT FROM `tble` GROUP BY class
```

Answer (score 0):

Make Count as column

```
select class, count(1) as Count
from table
group by class
```