# SQL, GROUP BY and INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

In addition to this question: [Comparing in SQL and SUM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460755/comparing-in-sql-and-sum)

I need some more help. At this point I have a View (lets call it inner-join-view) that joines two tables with an INNER JOIN. This is fine. Then I have another view which uses SUM+GROUP BY to sum up some data from the inner-join-view, which is fine. Now, however, I need data from the inner-join-view that doesn't have anything to do with the group by. Does that make sense? I can't just select it and then group it, because that creates a wrong calculation.

How can I come around this?

Answer (score 0):

To work with a "grouped" and "non-grouped" datas in the one SELECT you can use a "PARTITION BY"-Tag:
http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/analytical/index.html